# Sorting a string with special characters like this N/S,N/A

Tags: javascript

I need to sort a collection of strings, some of which contain special characters, in JavaScript.

Here is some examples to sort

```
N/S
N/A 
dd/mm/yy (Date format)
```

like in which these Strings are containing a special character '**/**'.

For now I'm using sort method on array which is not fixing the issue as expected.

Answer (score 3):

The examples you provide aren't helpful as you don't provide the sorting rules that go with them.

The `sort` method accepts (as an argument) a function which describes the sorting rules. Express your rules in that function. There are some examples of how to write this function in [the documentation for sort on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Hi, I'm also using the same function which is there in the Doc you have specified it is fine working if the string is without any special characters in my example like '/'. My rules are like this there are n no of dates of format dd/mm/yy how can I sort these strings in ascending or descending.

Comment: Then you need to add rules for how it is going to handle them. If it was *just* dates then you could split on `/` characters and then sort numerically by year (then month if they are the same and then day if they are the same). It sounds like your situation is more complicated then that though.